# how to write a generator for Keras fit_generator with a state?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, generator

I am trying to feed a large dataset to a keras model.
The dataset does not fit into memory.
It is currently stored as a serie of hd5f files

I want to train my model using

```
model.fit_generator(my_gen, steps_per_epoch=30, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

However, in all the examples I could find online, `my_gen` was used only to perform data augmentation on a already loaded dataset. For example

```
def generator(features, labels, batch_size):

 # Create empty arrays to contain batch of features and labels#

 batch_features = np.zeros((batch_size, 64, 64, 3))
 batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size,1))

 while True:
   for i in range(batch_size):
     # choose random index in features
     index= random.choice(len(features),1)
     batch_features[i] = some_processing(features[index])
     batch_labels[i] = labels[index]
   yield batch_features, batch_labels
```

In my case, it needs to be something like

```
def generator(features, labels, batch_size):    
 while True:
   for i in range(batch_size):
     # choose random index in features
     index= # SELECT THE NEXT FILE
     batch_features[i] = some_processing(features[files[index]])
     batch_labels[i] = labels[file[index]]
   yield batch_features, batch_labels
```

How do I keep track of the files which were already read in previous batch?

Answer (score 8):

[From the keras doc](https://keras.io/models/model/)

> generator: A generator or an instance of Sequence (keras.utils.Sequence) object in order to avoid duplicate data when using multiprocessing. [...]

This means you can write a class inheriting from keras.utils.sequence

```
class ProductSequence(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __len__(self):
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        pass
```

`__init__` ist to init the class. 
`__len__` should return the number of batches per epoch. Keras will use thisto know which index can be passed to `__getitem__`. `__getitem__` will then return the batch data depending on the index. 
A simple example can be found [here](https://keras.io/utils/)

With this approach you can simpy have an internal class object in which you save which files are already read.

Comment: This made my day. I was really confused about generators. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let us suppose that your data are images. If you have many images you probably won't be able to load all of them in memory and you would like to read from disk in batches.

`Keras` flow_from _directory is very fast in doing that as it does this in a multi threading way too but it needs all the images to be in different files, according to their class. If we have all the images in the same file and their classes in separated file we could use the generator bellow to load our x,y data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2

#df_train:  data frame with class of every image
#dpath: path of images

classes=list(np.unique(df_train.label)) 
def batch_generator(ids):
    while True:
        for start in range(0, len(ids), batch_size):
            x_batch = []
            y_batch = []
            end = min(start + batch_size, len(ids))
            ids_batch = ids[start:end]
            for id in ids_batch:
                img = cv2.imread(dpath+'train/{}.png'.format(id)) #open cv read as BGR
                #img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #BGR to RGB
                #img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                #img = pre_process(img)
                labelname=df_train.label.loc[df_train.id==id].values
                labelnum=classes.index(labelname)
                x_batch.append(img)
                y_batch.append(labelnum)
            x_batch = np.array(x_batch)
            y_batch = to_categorical(y_batch,10) 
            yield x_batch, y_batch
```

Comment: Does the warning `generator: a generator or an instance of Sequence (keras.utils.Sequence) object in order to avoid duplicate data when using multiprocessing.` apply here? It seems like this keeps track of where it is, so that it would not reuse an image until you looped all the way through. Perhaps a new question?